# PHP and HTML 5 validation message

Tags: php, html

I would like to know how do I edit in HTML5 validation message if there is error in form.

```
<form method="post" id="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <div class="form_settings">
        <label for="textfield">Meno:</label>
        <input class="zaoblene" type="text" name="meno" value="Meno....." onclick="javascript: document.forms['login'].meno.value=''" required>
        <br><br>
        <label for="textfield">Heslo:</label>
        <input class="zaoblene" type="password" name="heslo" value="heslo....." onclick="javascript: document.forms['login'].heslo.value=''" required>
        <br><br>
        <input class="prihlasit" type="submit" name="prihlasit" value="prihlásit" >
     </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: This form you posted isn't using any HTML form validation. What does it have to do with your question?

Comment: Where is the error to display?

Comment: Okay on an unrelated note, get rid of your action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" and replace it with action="". It'll do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **javascript** to do it!

Here you've the jquery plugin that does this work : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/